# How do I add remote images to a pdf using iTextPDF 5.5.13 in android?

Tags: java, android, image, itext

[image: Error screenshot]I want to create a customer invoice
    The invoice will then include a photo of each item with its price
    Each invoice can contain several items purchased by the customer
    So each bill can have multiple images
    Price and image information is taken from the website and stored in a list
    When I want to get the address of each photo and insert it into a file with the following code in a loop, the program crashes
    If I do this multiple times outside of a loop, the program will work correctly

this code work correctly for one image from asset folder

```
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = getContext().getAssets().open("logo1.png");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image signature;
        signature = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        signature.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 150f);
        signature.scalePercent(100f);
        signature.scaleAbsoluteHeight(50);
        signature.scaleAbsoluteWidth((signature.getWidth() * 50) / signature.getHeight());


        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(getResources().getString(R.string.total_price)));
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);


        c1 = new PdfPCell(signature);
        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(c1);



    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but in similar way below code for images from web not work

```
    Image imageFromWeb;
    if(orderProductsList.size()>0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < orderProductsList.size(); i++) {
            String img = ConstantValues.ECOMMERCE_URL + orderProductsList.get(i).getImage();

            try {
                imageFromWeb = Image.getInstance(new URL(img));
                imageFromWeb.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 150f);
                imageFromWeb.scalePercent(100f);
                imageFromWeb.scaleAbsoluteHeight(50);
                imageFromWeb.scaleAbsoluteWidth((imageFromWeb.getWidth() * 50) / imageFromWeb.getHeight());

                c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(getResources().getString(R.string.total_price)));
                c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(c1);


                c1 = new PdfPCell(imageFromWeb);
                c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(c1);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

this is my main code

```
  public void GenerateInvoicePdf() {
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/PDF/" + "Name.pdf";

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);


            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/PDF");
            myDir.mkdirs();


            try {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));


                document.open();


                addMetaData(document);
                addTitlePage(document);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            document.close();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PDF File is Created. Location : " + path,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        public void addMetaData(Document document)
        {
            document.addTitle("RESUME");
            document.addSubject("Person Info");
            document.addKeywords("Personal, Education, Skills");
            document.addAuthor("TAG");
            document.addCreator("TAG");
        }




        public void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException {
            Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 22, Font.BOLD
                    | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.GRAY);

            Paragraph prHead = new Paragraph();

            prHead.setFont(titleFont);
            prHead.add(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date())+"\n");
            prHead.add("\n Order Invoice \n\n");

            prHead.setFont(catFont);
            prHead.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            document.add(prHead);

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

            PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(getResources().getString(R.string.count_of_products)));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(c1);

            c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""+noOfProducts));
            c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            table.addCell(c1);



            Image imageFromWeb;
            if(orderProductsList.size()>0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < orderProductsList.size(); i++) {
                    String img = ConstantValues.ECOMMERCE_URL + orderProductsList.get(i).getImage();

                    try {
                        imageFromWeb = Image.getInstance(new URL(img));
                        imageFromWeb.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 150f);
                        imageFromWeb.scalePercent(100f);
                        imageFromWeb.scaleAbsoluteHeight(50);
                        imageFromWeb.scaleAbsoluteWidth((imageFromWeb.getWidth() * 50) / imageFromWeb.getHeight());

                        c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(getResources().getString(R.string.total_price)));
                        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        table.addCell(c1);


                        c1 = new PdfPCell(imageFromWeb);
                        c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                        table.addCell(c1);


                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            }



            document.add(table);
            }
```

/////        This is the error that is displayed after run app:

```
    2019-08-29 10:09:30.999 22114-22114/com.vectorcoder.androideco E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.vectorcoder.androideco, PID: 22114
        android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
            at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1072)
            at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:260)
            at com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(Image.java:241)
            at com.vectorcoder.androideco.fragments.Invoice_Details.addTitlePage(Invoice_Details.java:395)
            at com.vectorcoder.androideco.fragments.Invoice_Details.GenerateInvoicePdf(Invoice_Details.java:163)
            at com.vectorcoder.androideco.fragments.Invoice_Details.onCreateView(Invoice_Details.java:126)
            at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
            at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
            at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7124)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:898)
```

Comment: iText 5.5.13 does not exist for Android. The highest version of the Android port of iText, called iTextG, is version 5.5.10. See https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextg/5.5.10/jar

Comment: thanks Amedee but after change , there is still an error

Comment: I did not expect that fixing the version would fix your problem. Hopefully someone else can help you with that.

Comment: i added these commands and my problem solved:         StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: Put your answer in an actual answer, so others with the same problem can find it. :)